# C++14: Why can't I use braces for `void`?

Tags: c++, c++14, uniform-initialization, list-initialization

It's quite common (in my code at least) to use `decltype` and `std::enable_if_t` to have a simple and efficient SFINAE selection.  Something like the following:

```
template <typename A1, typename A2, typename... Auts>
inline
auto
infiltration(const A1& a1, const A2& a2, const Auts&... as)
  -> decltype(std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Auts) != 0>{},
              infiltration(infiltration(a1, a2), as...))
{
  return infiltration(infiltration(a1, a2), as...);
}
```

However, for some reason `void{}` is not valid (at least for Clang and GCC), so I can't write this: I must use `()` to instantiate my `std::enable_if_t`:

```
$ cat foo.cc
    auto foo() -> decltype(void()) {}
    auto bar() -> decltype(void{}) {}

    int main()
    {
      foo();
      bar();
    }
$ clang++-mp-3.6 -std=c++14 foo.cc
foo.cc:2:32: error: illegal initializer type 'void'
    auto bar() -> decltype(void{}) {}
                               ^
1 error generated.
$ clang++-mp-3.7 -std=c++14 foo.cc
foo.cc:2:32: error: illegal initializer type 'void'
    auto bar() -> decltype(void{}) {}
                               ^
1 error generated.
$ g++-mp-5 -std=c++14 foo.cc
foo.cc:2:33: error: compound literal of non-object type 'void'
     auto bar() -> decltype(void{}) {}
                                 ^
foo.cc:2:33: error: compound literal of non-object type 'void'
foo.cc: In function 'int main()':
foo.cc:7:11: error: 'bar' was not declared in this scope
       bar();
           ^
```

Why is that?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That's not quite right. void() in certain contexts designates a prvalue of void type.

Comment: Simple workaround is to commute the `enable_if` and `decltype`: `-> std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Auts) != 0, decltype(infiltration(infiltration(a1, a2), as...))>`.

Comment: @Casey Well, it makes a difference with Clang.  As I have written it, the recursive instantiation of `infiltration` is short-circuited by the `decltype`.  In your solution, the `enable_if` requires both its arguments before starting to work, so it instantiates nested `infiltration`s endlessly.  Unfortunately, it makes no difference for GCC 4.9, both fail.  So I'll add a third explicit argument to avoid the need for `enable_if`.